# How to keep iptables organized in Xenserver?

Tags: centos, iptables, xenserver

I need to use a couple of iptables rules to allow ports for additional services and implement some NATted services.

In `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` it says not to edit this file directly.  I understand there are some GUI/TUI tools included in CentOS/Xenserver and I also have the possibility to add these rules by calling init.d scripts via rc.d or network up scripts.

My simple question:
Is it safe to just adjust `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` or is there a better way in order to keep things simple and organized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, on a fairly large number of CentOS boxes, it is safe to edit that file **as long as you never use any other tool, including `iptables-save`, to edit the firewall**.

As a precaution against something else overwriting it, I use `rcs` to keep it under local source control, which has the other handy benefit of allowing point-in-time rollbacks, and some idea of who edited it, and why.